# mod_wsgi authentication script

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Can anybody help me? I've got a script like this:

Can anybody write me easy script for user's authentication without frameworks, but with Apache/mod_wsgi and DBM file. I've seen http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms,

but i need an example. I've got Python3.1, mod_wsgi3.2, Apache2.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Discussion about this was at:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_frm/thread/9378c1db3ba7bc43

Various suggestions given.

Comment: I really like the way you are actively supporting mod_wsgi. :)